# plot several lines out of the same two columns dataframe R

Tags: r

I would like to plot several lines of different time lenght in the same line graph out of the same dataframe. Then I want to set the X axis from 1 to X, being X the maximum number of periods of the line with maximum lenght.

For instance, line1 for years 1980 to 1989, line2 for years 1995 to 2001, etc. See data below for the data I use.

```r
dput(malineGDP)
structure(list(Year = c(1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "GDPpercent", class = "factor"), value = c(0.0277183930261643, 
0.0288427846071515, 0.0526348961735552, 0.0371487738221672, 0.0427232519007513, 
0.0704405101613155, 0.0771983341458076, 0.07685960434821, 0.111917681446816, 
0.082616933786008, 0.0426218080075034, 0.0287408712637852, 0.0283927466984115, 
0.0463085646932952, 0.0569077180354995, 0.0872515547548894, 0.0929491742150426, 
0.130132692280228, 0.200424443096016, 0.222006216429481, 0.191768530376496, 
0.0955005462614614, 0.0476287715422711, 0.0583828349263007, 0.0823773327852261, 
0.102928117429317, 0.133464508881022, 0.135900867106755, 0.0822682054263, 
0.0606165184312332, 0.0652403453525391, 0.0799398361449388, 0.0612558039666617, 
0.0721234864232935, 0.122718837613643, 0.132779681405992, 0.0954672321123404, 
0.0904404973441826, 0.0940829197015593, 0.0882826864405067, 0.0534565360036942, 
0.11095822366049)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")
```

I don't know how to start tbh

Answer (score 2):

using ggplot2 for graphs

```
malineGDP$line=""
malineGDP$line[malineGDP$Year>=1980 & malineGDP$Year<=1989]="line1"
malineGDP$line[malineGDP$Year>=1995 & malineGDP$Year<=2001]="line2"

malineGDP$X=ave(malineGDP$Year,malineGDP$line,FUN=function(i){i-min(i)+1})

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(malineGDP,aes(y=value,x=X,group=line,color=line)) + geom_line() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(period = case_when(between(Year, 1980, 1989) ~ "1980-1989", 
                          between(Year, 1995, 2001) ~ "1995-2001", 
                          TRUE ~ "Other")) %>% 
  group_by(period) %>%  
  mutate(time = 1:n()) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = time, y = value, col = period) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5) + 
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Without "Other"

```
df %>% 
  mutate(period = case_when(between(Year, 1980, 1989) ~ "1980-1989", 
                          between(Year, 1995, 2001) ~ "1995-2001", 
                          TRUE ~ "Other")) %>% 
  filter(period != "Other") %>% 
  group_by(period) %>%  
  mutate(time = 1:n()) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = time, y = value, col = period) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5) + 
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could put `y`ears in a vector, initialize an empty `plot`, and use `lines` on a subset of the data frame which `lengths` are adjusted by `max` length.

```
y <- list(1980:1989, 1995:2001, 2017:2021)

plot(seq_len(max(lengths(y))), ylim=range(dat$value), type='n', ylab='value', main='plot')
lapply(y, \(y) dat[dat$Year %in% y, 'value']) |>
  lapply(`length<-`, max(lengths(y))) |>
  Map(lines, x=_, col=seq_along(y) + 1)
legend('topright', legend=lapply(y, range) |> lapply(paste, collapse=':'), lty=1, col=seq_along(y) + 1)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Year = c(1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "GDPpercent", class = "factor"), value = c(0.0277183930261643, 
0.0288427846071515, 0.0526348961735552, 0.0371487738221672, 0.0427232519007513, 
0.0704405101613155, 0.0771983341458076, 0.07685960434821, 0.111917681446816, 
0.082616933786008, 0.0426218080075034, 0.0287408712637852, 0.0283927466984115, 
0.0463085646932952, 0.0569077180354995, 0.0872515547548894, 0.0929491742150426, 
0.130132692280228, 0.200424443096016, 0.222006216429481, 0.191768530376496, 
0.0955005462614614, 0.0476287715422711, 0.0583828349263007, 0.0823773327852261, 
0.102928117429317, 0.133464508881022, 0.135900867106755, 0.0822682054263, 
0.0606165184312332, 0.0652403453525391, 0.0799398361449388, 0.0612558039666617, 
0.0721234864232935, 0.122718837613643, 0.132779681405992, 0.0954672321123404, 
0.0904404973441826, 0.0940829197015593, 0.0882826864405067, 0.0534565360036942, 
0.11095822366049)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")
```